Error building Flet app - see the log of failed command above
I tried "flet build apk" command using cmd (using administrative and non administrative). But here the result when I try it. If anyone can help me to fix that issue it will be so much thankful.
Unhandled exception:
PathAccessException: Deletion failed, path = 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\hostpython3.11_475fccd2' (OS Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. , errno = 32)

#0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:55:9)

#1      _Directory._delete.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:180:7)

<asynchronous suspension>`

#2      PackageCommand.run

(file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/serious_python-.7.0/bin/package_command.dart:363:9)

<asynchronous suspension>

#3      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)`

<asynchronous suspension>

#4      main (file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/serious_python- .7.0/bin/main.dart:10:3)

<asynchronous suspension>

Error building Flet app - see the log of failed command above.


This seems to be a file-access conflict.
Some solutions are --

Restart your PC
Check if any background process is locking that directory. (It's better to close all unnecessary apps through Task Manager)
Check for Antivirus Interference: Sometimes antivirus software can lock files
Try a Different Directory: If possible, try running the flet build apk command in a different directory that you have full control over and ensure no other processes are using it

You can also try taking full-ownership of your directory. Check this out
